# Rails Strip Method Not Working Correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strip, gsub

So just in case someone stumbles across the same issue, I have a string:

`a = "  I am a string with whitespace at the start and end "`

Interestingly when trying to `a.strip`, my string **didn't** change to:

`a = "I am a string with whitespace at the start and end"`

Comment: I had the same issue again with `squish` and `.squeeze(' ')`. My answer works as well in those cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here was, that I had `&nbsp;` or some other kind of space which prevented `strip` from doing what it does best.

My solution, first replace all my spaces with spaces:

`a.gsub("\u00A0", " ")` (I tried `a.gsub("&nbsp;", " ")` at first, but no luck)

tada!

Now I got my expected `a.strip` result :)

(Maybe there is a clearer way to do this, if so let me know)